# Ejs variables in script tag/ setting array to variable become string

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, variables, ejs

So i needed to pass a variable to the script tag in the ejs file. it's  question array (i called it object in the var name for no reason), that i need to work with in the script tag. i saw that it's done by  `'<%-varname%>'` .
But the thing is, i want to remove stuff from the array while working with it, so i need a copy of this array. And here is the problem:

```
console.log('<%-passedUser.questionsObject%>')
console.log('<%-passedUser.questionsObject[0]%>')
arrayToUse = '<%-passedUser.questionsObject%>'
console.log(arrayToUse)
console.log(arrayToUse[0])
```

### Output:

```
question1,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,answer5,q2,answer1,answer2 

question1,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,answer5 

question1,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,answer5,q2,answer1,answer2 

q
```

I tried `JSON.stringify`, parse, nothing works. i'd appreciate any help.

Note: i don't know why `'<%-passedUser.questionsObject%>'` isn't logging the correct way, but it's giving correct values. It's true form is :

```
[[question1,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,answer5],[q2,answer1,answer2]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use both json parse and json stringify

```
arrayToUse = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(passedUser.questionsObject)%>')
```

later you can easily split the array using

```
const [questions,answers] = arrayToUse
```

or do it before sending it to the client

```
<% const [questions,answers] = passedUser.questionsObject %>

<script>
  const  arrayToUse = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(questions)%>')
</script>
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine, thanks! But can i ask why and when does that happen?